Why seaborn shows so big intervals
I have dataset where min = 0, and max = 50,6. When I plot distributions of data seaborn plost data from 0 to 400. Why?!
I thought tah seaborn shows interval from 0 to 50.6
command:
sns.displot(june_df['Продолжительность погрузки, мин'], kde=True)

and I got this:


Not sure why it does this, but you can use plt.xlim([0, 50]) to change the limits of the x axis.

But I used seaborn, not mathplotlib...

Seaborn uses matplotlib internally, so you can use a lot of matplotlib stuff to manipulate seaborn plots. If the suggestion above doesn't work, you can also look at How to change the X axis range in seaborn

how do you know the max value is 50? looking at the plot you have data until 430 approx

No. I have data, and I see them. Also I used describes method and max value 50.6

@NickODell thank you very much, your advice helped me.

Now I am used this solution:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

data = june_df['Продолжительность погрузки, мин'] 

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sns.histplot(data, ax=ax)  # distplot is deprecate and replaced by histplot
ax.set_xlim(0,51)
ax.set_xticks(range(0,51))
plt.show()



If you want to ignore the data larger than 50.6, you can write sns.histplot(data[data < 50.6]). That way, the kde curve will only be calculated on that range (being much smoother).  It is very strange that you insist your data is already limited to 50.6 while your plot clearly shows you have data larger than 400.

Agree? that is strange. But I checked data twice and there aren't number more than 50.6.

Simply print(data.max()) to see the maximum. Be assured that Seaborn doesn't invent data that aren't there.  How are you checking the data? There are more than 30000 values. Please think again.

before I used method describes() and it showed max=50.6 You think that mathplotlib could find new numbers?

I found why interval was from 0 to 566... because data whas between 0 to 50.6 But! I used  function 'subtotal' in excel, where from I load data. And I didn't delete function and its result.
